# Naming convention for mutating functions in Swift

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

In Ruby, mutating methods (i.e. methods that modify self) are, by convention marked with a bang (!) to separate them from the similary named methods that do not modify self.

For instance `Array#sort` returns a sorted array, but `Array#sort!` modifies the array on which it is called.

I've now started looking into Swift. How would I name a mutating method to separate it from its non-mutating twin?

I know that Python has `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`. Is that a good pattern to follow, i.e `.sorted()` (non-mutating) and `.sort()` (mutating)?

How about names that are not readily transformed in that way, such as `String#next` vs `String#next!`?

Comment: In Swift 2, `sorted()` and `sort()` were renamed to  `sort()` and `sortInPlace()`.

Comment: This might be useful: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/.

Comment: I did not think about that. I was not actually thinking about a particular method, but rather tried finding general advice, but could not find any.  For instance in [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1): Extensions section on Mutating Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID155) they use `square()` for a mutating method.

Comment: OK, thanks, the link provided gives the necessary information.

I was googling for terms in that document, but somehow missed it.

* Those without side-effects should read as noun phrases, e.g. `x.distanceTo(y)`, `i.successor()`.

* Those with side-effects should read as imperative verb phrases, e.g., `print(x)`, `x.sort()`, `x.append(y)`.

* Use the “ed/ing” rule to name the nonmutating counterpart of a mutating method, e.g. `x.sort()`/`x.sorted()` and `x.append(y)`/`x.appending(y)`.

Comment: But, if that is the change made in Swift 2, i.e that `sort()` is non-mutating, and `sortInPlace()` is mutating, the advice in the api design guidelines is... confusing... I must say I really like Ruby´s bang method convention...

Comment: On the Swift-Evolution mailing list they are having a long and tedious discussion about the naming conventions for Swift 3. Once they've decided what the answer is, they'll be posting API naming guidelines.

Answer (score 12):

About posting the official guidelines, here they are:
https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#name-according-to-side-effects

> **Name Mutating/nonmutating method pairs** consistently. A mutating method will often have a nonmutating variant with similar semantics, but that returns a new value rather than updating an instance in-place.
>
> - When the operation is **naturally described by a verb**, use the verb’s imperative for the mutating method and apply the “ed” or “ing” suffix to name its nonmutating counterpart.
>
>   ```
>   Mutating    Nonmutating
>   x.sort()    z = x.sorted()
>   x.append(y) z = x.appending(y)
>   ```
>
>   Prefer to name the nonmutating variant using the verb’s past [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) (usually appending “ed”):
>
>   ```
>   /// Reverses `self` in-place.
>   mutating func reverse()
>
>   /// Returns a reversed copy of `self`.
>   func reversed() -> Self
>   ...
>   x.reverse()
>   let y = x.reversed()
>   ```
>
>   When adding “ed” is not grammatical because the verb has a direct object, name the nonmutating variant using the verb’s present [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), by appending “ing.”
>
>   ```
>   /// Strips all the newlines from `self`
>   mutating func stripNewlines()
>
>   /// Returns a copy of `self` with all the newlines stripped.
>   func strippingNewlines() -> String
>   ...
>   s.stripNewlines()
>   let oneLine = t.strippingNewlines()
>   ```
> - When the operation is **naturally described by a noun**, use the noun for the nonmutating method and apply the “form” prefix to name its mutating counterpart.
>
>   ```
>   Nonmutating         Mutating
>   x = y.union(z)      y.formUnion(z)
>   j = c.successor(i)  c.formSuccessor(&i)
>   ```

[Ray Wenderlich](https://twitter.com/rwenderlich) sums it up in its own [Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming):

> verb methods follow the -ed, -ing rule for the non-mutating version
>   noun methods follow the formX rule for the non-mutating version

Note that the official guidelines were updated for Swift 3 thanks to Proposal: SE-0059 by [Dave Abrahams](https://twitter.com/DaveAbrahams), [Update API Naming Guidelines and Rewrite Set APIs Accordingly](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0059-updated-set-apis.md), after approval on 18th April 2016.

But five days before, on 13th April 2016, [Erica Sadun](https://twitter.com/ericasadun) expressed a somewhat different opinion in her article [Stop the Madness and fix the Swift API guidelines](http://ericasadun.com/2016/04/13/stop-the-madness-and-fix-the-swift-api-guidelines/). Let's add that Erica previously wrote her own article on the matter, [Naming Methods and Functions](http://ericasadun.com/2015/08/31/naming-methods-and-functions/), also available in her book **Swift Style**. And for the fun, she attempted to [explain mutating naming with emoji](https://twitter.com/ericasadun/status/795063627120340992).